# Fast binary protocol that can be serialized/deserialized in Scala and in a browser

Tags: java, javascript, performance, binary, websocket

I have a websockets connection sending data to and from the server. I am thinking it will be fastest if I use a binary protocol to serialise and deserialise all messages instead of using JSON.

Are there any existing tools that would do this that work in Java/Scala and JavaScript?

Comment: Could try Google Protocol Buffer. Concise, binary, and while JS is not officially supported, there are projects for it... Question is: do you really need that optimization? Is this really the problem you need to solve?

Comment: Unless you have a measurable performance problem, you should just use JSON.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: No I possibly don't need this. My question was mostly speculative, wondering if any gains were possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You probably do not need to as you probably won't notice the gain.

There is BSON http://bsonspec.org/ which is binary JSON. Explain more what kind of data and the amount of data you are dealing with if you really think you need to.